# Rotational potential energy on a system of two masses

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy

On a homework assignment, we were given the following problem:
 [image]

This system is held at equilibrium according to the configuration in the image; initially the body B is at rest, and the body A is rotating with angular velocity $\omega = \omega_0$. The plane is rigid and frictionless, and the string connecting the two masses is ideal and has length $l$; furthermore, there is no friction between the plane and the string.

> 1) Sketch a free body diagram for each body
>
> 2) Write down the motion equation for each body
>
> 3) Determine the acceleration of the body B immediately after the system is released from rest
>
> 4) Determine whether or not, and under what conditions the body B can move upwards after the system is released.

Now, the problem itself is easy enough; however, I'd like to go beyond and determine the general evolution of the system, or at least decide whether it has stable configurations around which it can oscillate. Here's my work so far:

Noting that the string's length is invariant we have that
$$ z+r=l \Rightarrow \ddot{z}=-\ddot{r} $$
Now, eliminating the tension from both motion equations, we get the following relation:
$$ m_b\ddot{r} = m_a \omega ^2 r - m_b g $$
Since the tension acting on body A is a central force, the angular momentum relative to the hole in the plane is conserved. Thus,
$$ L = m_a \omega r^2 \Rightarrow \dot{L} = m_a(\dot{\omega}r^2 + 2\omega r \dot{r}) = 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{\dot{\omega}}{\omega} = -2\frac{\dot{r}}{r} $$
Integration of both sides leads to
$$ \omega = \frac{C}{r^2} $$
where $C$ is a (positive?) constant which I don't quite know how to determine using the data given on the problem, although I don't think it's so relevant right now. Substituting $\omega$ in the equation of motion, we get 
$$ m_b\ddot{r} = m_a \frac{C^2}{r^3}- m_b g $$

which is a second order ODE, meaning that it can be solved for $r$ and consequently for $\omega$, although I'm ashamed to admit that I don't exactly know how. Intuition tells that there must be some way of balancing $\omega$ and $r$ in such a way that the system oscillates, so my next step was to try analyzing the potential energy of the system, in hopes of finding any maximum/minima generating a potential well in which the system oscillates. However, there is only one field force acting on the system -- the approximately constant gravitational force on body B -- and that would imply that the potential doesn't have any maxima/minima.

Now, I've seen the idea of a "rotational potential" being used in problems before (more specifically in the problem of determining the shape of the surface of water in a rotating bucket), so I was wondering if it is "legal" to account for the following
$$ \frac{1}{2} m_a \omega ^2 r^2 $$ 
on the potential of the system, which would make the potential effectively have critical points. If that's the case, what's exactly the
 idea behind this "potential rotational energy"? Where does it arise from, and what justifies its use on this problem?